# My logging framework is tied to my application forever!

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nlog

Ok, so I'm looking at NLog. Based on the usage, my application would be tied to the logging framework. How do I overcome this?

Also, when using NLog, I have to write too much `monkey-code` for every class I'm using this framework on. Is it a good practice to make one static class and access it from anywhere in my application?

example:

```
//the monkey code
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

//the coupling.
logger.Log(/*...*/);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create your own logging interface:

   ```
   public interface IMyOwnLogger {
       void Log(string message);
   }
   ```
2. Create implementation:

   ```
   public class NLogLogger : IMyOwnLogger {
       void Log(string message) {
           StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1, false);
           Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger(frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.FullName);
           logger.Log(/*...*/);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Bind IMyOwnLogger to NLogLogger in your IOC container.
4. Inject where needed (or use `IOC.Get<IMyOwnLogger>()`).

**EDIT:**

Idsa made a comment about loosing calling class. Remember you can always use stack trace:

```
var method = (new StackTrace()).GetFrame(1).GetMethod()
```

and extract calling class from there.

**EDIT:**

This is how `GetCurrentClassLogger` in NLog looks like, so using StackTrace in our class doesn't create additional overhead:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static Logger GetCurrentClassLogger()
{
    #if SILVERLIGHT
    StackFrame frame = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1);
    #else
    StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1, false);
    #endif

    return globalFactory.GetLogger(frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.FullName);
}
```

Comment: You lost the interface in your class declaration. Also it'd better `MyOwnLogger` accepted the `logger` instance as a constructor param - that is how DI works.

Comment: I don't thing LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger makes sense here: it will be created for MyOwnLogger but not for the real place where logging was called

Comment: @zerkms: Thanks. I've added interface. `NLogLogger` class is IMyOwnLogger implementation using NLog, so it doesn't have to take logger in constructor.

Comment: The one disadvantage of this solution is that we lose the class name that called logging. I think it is a very significant loss

Comment: @Idsa: I made additional comment about it. It is not totally lost.

Comment: @LukLed: But then we will have to use reflection for every logging call :(

Comment: @Idsa: Look at my edit. Using `StackTrace` doesn't really create overhead.

Comment: @LukLed: The difference is GetCurrentClassLogger is usually called once per class (when logger instance is stored as class field) but here we have to use reflection for every loggin call

Comment: I dont understand how to use this. Could I have an example of how I'd use it with having it know the class of which it has been called?

Comment: @Lol coder: I've changed `NLogLogger` class to use logger related to class, which is calling `Log` function.

Comment: Old question, I know, but I'm concerned about the use of StackFrame for a different reason - JIT inlining can render its data worse than useless; any method that logged something would in turn be required to use `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]`, no?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I avoid tying any logging framework to my code by using 
[TraceSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx) to [instrument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_%28computer_programming%29) my code.  I then use a logging framework (typically Enterprise Library's Logging Application Block) to "listen" to trace output at runtime and do whatever is necessary with that information. (i.e. write to a database, send emails, etc)

Comment: Any type of logging can have performance impacts under the right conditions (system load, etc). If your question is aimed at comparing the performance of a Logging Framework vs. using TraceSource and Trace Listeners, I would say it's safe to assume performance differences between the two is negligible.

Comment: I would also point out that Microsoft instruments its own class libraries using Tracing. A prime example of this is WCF (Windows Communication Foundation).  You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)